# Sum of independent exponential distributions?

Tags: probability-distributions

A person has $100$ light bulbs whose lifetimes are independent exponentials with mean $5$ hours. The bulbs are used one at a time, with a failed bulb being replaced immediately by a new one.

(a) Approximate the probability that there is still a working bulb after $525$ hours.

(b) Suppose that it takes a random time, uniformly distributed over $(0,0.5)$, to replace a failed
bulb. Approximate the probability that all bulbs have failed by time $550$.

Here is my work:

Here is what I know:

For a sequence of random variable $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ where they all have the same distribution we have:

\begin{equation}
\mu = E(X_i)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sigma^2 = \operatorname{Var}(X_i)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
S_n = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\overline{X}_n = \frac{S_n}{n}=\frac{X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n}{n}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
P\left(a \leq \frac{S_n - n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}} \leq b\right) \approx \Phi(b) - \Phi(a)
\end{equation}

$\overline{X}_n$ and $S_n$ approximately follows a normal distribution

so for

$a)$ here is what I did:

Let $X = $ lifetime of each lightbulb, $X_i\sim\exp(\lambda)$, and $\lambda = \frac{1}{5}$

Then $S_n = \sum_iX_i$, $\mu = 5$, $\sigma^2=25$

So I'm looking for $P(S_n>525)$

This turns into 
\begin{equation}
P\left(\frac{S_n - n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}} > \frac{525-n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}\right)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
P(Z>0.5) = 1 - P(Z<0.5) =0.308
\end{equation}

$b)$ Here is what I did:

Let $U_i\sim\mathrm{uniform}(0, 0.5)$.

Therefor $U_n = \sum_iU_i$

and I said let $L_n = U_n + S_n$ and $\mu_L = E(U) + E(X)$

and since $U_i$ and $X_i$ are independent I said $\sigma_L^2 = \operatorname{Var}(U_i) + \operatorname{Var}(X_i)$

Thus following same logic as $a)$ gives me

\begin{equation}
P\left(\frac{L_n - n\mu_L}{\sigma_L\sqrt{n}} < \frac{550-n\mu_L}{\sigma_L\sqrt{n}}\right)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
P(Z<0.5) = 0.691
\end{equation}

Is this correct? I made some assumptions on $b)$ so I'm not sure.

Comment: It looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer seems fine. I just have one word of caution. It says that each *replacement* follows a uniform distribution. With 100 bulbs, there are only 99 replacements. It is possible that you have to take that into account. Otherwise, it looks fine.

Comment: Wow good catch. I think you are right. It makes more sense. I will change my answer accordingly.

Comment: It's just a warning. I would check with an instructor or TA to see what they want. It is possible that despite the wording, they mean for you to add 100 of them, not 99.